# Was there a song about the year 5773 being special?

Tags: calendar, music

I recall as a kid hearing a tape with some song that went, "in the year tav-shin-ayin-gimel..." [5773], does that ring any bells? What was supposed to be special about that year?

Comment: Is this not a guessing game question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The song you’re thinking of is Country Yossi’s parody of *In the Year 2525*. (The lyrics were included in the Tishre 5773/September 2012 issue of Country Yossi Magazine.)

There’s no significance to 5773 except for the rhyme.

Comment: Not true! 5773 years ago the world was created! I think that's pretty significant!